# how to allow multiple async routes in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes, event-loop

I'm fairly new to Node and Express and am struggling with creating a route that takes a user uploaded file and processes it into another file. The problem is that the second time the user sends a request, I am having to wait for the first process to complete to allow the user to upload a new file.

The basic structure of route that I have is below

THE PROBLEM is that the function `convertFile` below is a time taking process and it keeps the server busy from accepting new requests. How do I make it so that once the project is saved in mongo db at `newProject.save()` - the process to `convertFile` runs in the background while the server accepts new requests from the same route?

I'm sending a response back the user after `newProject.save()` and was hoping that would allow the user to send another request. And although this sends another request, the server doesn't accept it since its busy with the previous process to `convertFile`

```js
router.post('/', upload.fields([{ name: 'zip' }]), async (req, res, next) => {
  let data = {
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
  }

  if (req.files && req.files.zip) {
    const newProject = new MongoProject(data);
    newProject.save()
      .then(async (project) => {
        res.send(project);
        console.log("Project created");


        const uploadedFilePath = path.normalize(req.files.zip[0].path);

        // below method - "convertFile" is a time taking method
        const extractZipinfo = await convertFile(uploadedFilePath , data.masterFile).then((zipInfo) => {
          console.log({ zipInfo })

          data.zipInfo = {
            sizes: zipInfo.sizes
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error creating project");
        return res.send(err);
      })

  }
})
```

Below is the simplified version of code in `convertFile` function (code modified for brevity):
I know that this can be improvised a lot, but i'm struggling with getting it to function as expected first (allowing multiple routes)

```js
async function convertFile(inputFilePath, outputInfo) {
    const outputFilePath = "output.abc";
    const jsonFilePath = "output.json";
    const doc = new Document(); // this is a class to store all data of the output file that we will write at the end

    const _FileAPI = new fileAPI();
    const outputFinalData = await _FileAPI.Init() // this is an async method
        .then(() => {
            const dataClass = initiateClass(); // this is a class to store data in JSON format
            const paragraphs = _FileAPI.GetallParagraphs(inputFilePath);
            for (let i = 0, len = paragraphs.size(); i < len; i++) {
                for (let j = 0, lenj = paragraphs.size(); j < lenj; j++) {
                    const para = paragraphs.get(j);
                    // read each para and Capitalize each word
                    dataClass.paragraphs.push(para);
                }
            }
            fs.writeFileSync(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(dataClass, null, 2), 'utf-8');
            console.log("then")
        }).then(() => {
            const io = new NodeIO(); // this class helps in writing the file in the desired output format
            const outData = io.write(outputFilePath, doc).then(() => {
                outputInfo.sizes.push(fs.statSync(outputFilePath).size);
                return outputInfo;
            });
            return outData;
        });
    return outputFinalData;
}
```

Comment: depends on what `convertFile` does. javascript is singlethreaded, and once it started a synchronous process, it won't be interrupted.

Comment: I have added a simplified version of `convertFile` function

Comment: You shouldn't use `writeFileSync` or `statSync` in an async environment. I don't know what `_FileApi.GetAllParagraphs` is, but it seems to be synchronous, which may be blocking the process. And you maybe should invest a little time in reading about how the JS eventloop and async work ...

Comment: Yes, `_FileApi.GetAllParagraphs` is a synchronous function that I use from an external package, so i'm not sure if I can make it asynchronous.

Comment: And, I found [an article](https://snyk.io/blog/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io/) related to async and event loops (which looks like a really good resource), but i'm not sure I completely understand it, given my experience. I'm still looking into it and hopefully will get some clarity soon